# How should I handle my response from the error on NODEJS?

Tags: node.js, http, request, request-promise

I am trying to use a `username` and `password` to login in website and get the session token.
The username and password actually works and it logins in the system but the problem is that the `session token` shows inside the error response.

Is it a good idea to parse the error and get session token?
Why its shown inside the error?

Here is the code:

```js
const rp = require('request-promise')


const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  uri: 'https://superset.simurgbilisim.com/login/',
  json: true,
  form: {
    username: 'test',
    password: 'test'
  }
};

rp(options)
  .then(function(body) {
    console.log(body);

  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Comment: A 302 response isn't an error, it's a (temporary) redirect.

Comment: I changed my question's title.

Comment: Without more information it's difficult to answer. What does the error response look like, for instance? And why the server would choose to return a session token inside an error response is a question for the person that implemented the server.

Comment: I am using an opensource library called `superset`. Its login mechanism creates a session token.